# How to prove that the vector field will be symmetric if it’s curl is given to be symmetric?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, vector-fields, symmetry

Actually, I need to deduce something about the nature of a vector field if it's curl is known completely without actually solving the partial differential equations.

Let's say we have a vector field $\mathbf B$ which depends only on the distance $r$ (perpendicular to z-axis) and points in positive $z$ direction. [I apologize for not being able to put it in single word, I meant that field $\mathbf B$ is such that it points in positive  z axis  but it's magnitude changes only when we move radially outward from the z axis (or origin), it is zero at the origin]. Then, if we have something like this $$ \nabla \times \mathbf A = \mathbf B$$ 
can we conclude that there exist an $\mathbf A$ such that it will have similar symmetry, that is moving circumferentially in $xy$ plane would not result in the change of magnitude of $\mathbf A$? And can we conclude that $\mathbf A$ will form closed loops because it has a non-zero curl? And if we take the above two information to be true we will get $\mathbf A$ as a circular field in $xy$ plane.

It is said that above mentioned conclusions about $\mathbf A$ are true due to *symmetry* and it is also said that if $\mathbf A$ would not have those properties then $\mathbf B$ will also not have the properties which is **given**, because they are related by the equation $$\nabla \times \mathbf A = \mathbf B$$

---

Let's consider another scenario, suppose that we have a vector field $\mathbf F$ in $xy$ plane which is uniform both in magnitude and direction all over the $xy$ plane and points in positive $x$ direction, something like this

[image].

And again if we have something like this $$ \nabla \times \mathbf V = \mathbf F$$ so, can we say that there exits a $\mathbf V$ such that it will also point in one particular direction like $\mathbf F$ and will have same uniformity like $\mathbf F$ ?

---

I have described my problem through the means of two simple scenarios, it should be noted that I'm not looking for their solutions. I want to understand how does a symmetrical curl implies a symmetrical operand?

My main question is: [How] can we deduce something about the symmetry of operand given the symmetry of its curl without actually solving the partial differential equations?

Comment: You can't, if you perturb $A$ by any gradient field, the curl doesn't change ( $\nabla \times ( A + \nabla \phi ) = \nabla \times A$). Perhaps a better question is given $B$ with certain symmetry, can you find an $A$ with same symmetry and $\nabla \times A = B$.

Comment: @achillehui Well Okay! Thanks for making my question clearer.

Comment: @achillehui Is my question correct now?

Comment: You're ignoring the whole question of whether $\mathbf B$ is a curl at all (just having divergence $0$ won't do it if there are singularities, as it likely with your symmetry condition). But if there is no topological restriction (e.g., no singularities), then I know a fancy proof of your *modified question* (existence of *some* $\mathbf A$ with the symmetry) using differential forms and invariance under a group action. I haven't thought about translating the argument into classical notation.

Comment: @TedShifrin Let’s assume there are no topological restrictions.